# Downloading image to webdav folder from url with new name and retrieve

Tags: php, redirect, webdav, imagedownload, rightnow-crm

Hi I have this PHP code (Custom Script) to query for FileAttachment URL from RightNow Incidents,

```
<?php 
define("CUSTOM_SCRIPT", true);
define(DEBUG, false);
define(COMMIT, true);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$ip_dbreq = true;
require_once( get_cfg_var("doc_root")."/ConnectPHP/Connect_init.php" );
use RightNow\Connect\v1_2 as RNCPHP;
try{
    initConnectAPI('user','Pass'); 
}
catch(Exception $error) { 
    echo $error->getMessage();
}
$img_url = "";
$inc_id = 296;
$entity = RNCPHP\Incident::fetch($inc_id);
foreach($entity->FileAttachments as $fileattach) {

    $img_url = $fileattach->getAdminURL();  
}
    $img_id = 23;
    $image_location = HTMLROOT . "/euf/assets/images/integration_images/images/".$inc_id."-".$img_id.".png";
    file_put_contents($img_url, fopen( $image_location , 'r'));
    header('Location: $image_location');
?>
```

This will return the file downloading url which if opened in browser will automatically download the image to my computer

URL : https://host.com/cgi-bin/some.cfg/php/admin/console_util/fa_get.php?p_parms=eUofFOziR6q7tVDrMAkPfz_F0iz5Nf17TjtEH18Z72PdbM9JJq6g4VNUF4oXfPY~UpgHsJhH0Nr7KKYBg78sV69A2pcj3h1cn5_mRTSyJtQHtkwQz8bqcldb8gjEUwtfQkgPVNx3u1jHjCESYm7aXKv7v4zqVV1_f_MTJp1ooey9tMHBsFlsKw0jQjurEl15gIeFNt011UglH3ccOhCvgimvVmsMvs2HbrVymNwZ1HmMtKewDQfdCy35Oi5kgotrQHoJ3QQn10fuGTjlrjgW1MEXncdTUHx2645YZxlmraur7_mpIJzWw9Rg!!

I want to use this url to download the image directly to Customer Portal folder
"/euf/assets/images/" with incident ID and Image ID as name, then build a new url for that image and redirect my above script to that image url so that we can see the image on browser directly.

Answer (score 0):

Send the content type header before the location header so that the browser knows the endpoint is an image.

This approach is dangerous, though, because you are basically exposing protected incident data on the public internet as assets is not a secured folder.